# Image won't show up after passing ImageSource instance from one ViewModel to another

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I'm trying to make a simple jigsaw puzzle. First the user imports a photo from his library, then the image is displayed letting the user confirm, that this is the one, that he wants to use. Then he presses a "Play" button, which opens up a new content page, which should ALSO display the exact same image.

I'm using MVVM in this project.

The first ContentPage has an Image which is bound to a ImageSource property in the ViewModel.

When the ImageSource is set, it is also copied to a SharedData class.

When the user presses the "Play" button a new ContentPage is loaded, and the same Image should appear loading the ImageSource from the SharedData class.

However this does not happen!

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

To put it simple, I just want to share the image between ViewModels (classes) in a very simple way. The task is not to set up some complicated architecture. I just want this little thing to work.

**StartViewModel:**

```
        // Image
    private ImageSource _imageSource = "";
    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;
            SharedData.ImageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
            <Image Margin="0,100,0,0" Source="{Binding ImgSource}" BackgroundColor="Black"></Image>
```

This works fine, however when passing the ImageSource to the SharedData class or as a parameter in the MainViewModel it goes wrong

**MainViewModel (The second view):**

```
        // Image
    private ImageSource _imageSource = "mouse.jpg";
    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SwapCMD = new CommandDelegate(action: x => { Console.WriteLine("Ignore this line"); }, executable: x => { return true; });

        ImgSource = SharedData.ImageSource;

    }
```

And as you can see I have bound the ImageSource the same way as in the previous view:

XAML:

```
        <Image Margin="0,100,0,0" Source="{Binding ImgSource}" BackgroundColor="Black"></Image>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I just pass the source to another view like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. I am not sure why you use a SharedData class to store the imagesource at first time. But, when you pass the imagesource from one viewmodel to another, you could pass it directly.

StartPage.xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Image
            Margin="0,100,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="Black"
            Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnPlay"
            Clicked="btnPlay_Clicked"
            Text="Play" />
    </StackLayout>
```

StartViewModel.cs

```
public class StartViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ImageSource _imageSource = "";
    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged("ImgSource");
        }
    }

    public StartViewModel()
    {
        ImgSource = "pink.jpg";
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

StartPage.xaml.cs

```
  public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new StartViewModel();
    }

    private async void btnPlay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
  <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <Image
        Margin="0,100,0,0"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />

</StackLayout>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Image
    private ImageSource _imageSource = "";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImgSource");

        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //SwapCMD = new CommandDelegate(action: x => { Console.WriteLine("Ignore this line"); }, executable: x => { return true; });

        ImgSource = new StartViewModel().ImgSource;

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
```

[image]